# Assign the same value to object keys from lambda in Python (Django)

Tags: python-3.x, django

When trying to assign the same value to `starting_bid` and `price` from the `Listing` model in my Django project the below approach always yields different values. How can I assign the same value while still having the lambda return a random integer whenever the test runs?

**tests.py**

```py
SEEDER = Seed.seeder() # from django_seed
AMOUNT = 15
MIN = 5
MAX = 84
PRICE = lambda x: random.randint(MIN, MAX)

SEEDER.add_entity(
Listing, 
AMOUNT, 
{
  "starting_bid": PRICE, 
  "price": PRICE
})

SEEDER.execute()
```

**Result:**

```
{"starting_bid": 80, "price": 45}
```

**Expected:**

```
{"starting_bid": 80, "price": 80}
```

**models.py**

```py
class Listing(models.Model):
    CATEGORIES = (("LAP", "Laptop"), ("CON", "Console"), ("GAD", "Gadget"), ("GAM", "Game"), ("TEL", "TV"))
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    starting_bid = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    price = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    image_url = models.URLField(max_length=200)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=8, choices=CATEGORIES)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

Comment: If the whole code runs in execution, why do you want to use `lambda` function ?

Comment: you haven't added any info about where are these results coming from? What exact statement is yielding these results?

Answer (score 0):

```py
_price = []
def PRICE(round = 2):
  global _price
  if not _price:
    _price = random.randint(MIN, MAX)
    _price = [_price] * round
  return _price.pop()
```